# Find the extreme values of $f(x,y)=x^2y$ in $D=\{x^2+8y^2\leq24\}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find the extreme values of $f(x,y)=x^2y$ in $D=\{x^2+8y^2\leq24\}$

It was easy to find using Lagrange multipliers the local extreme values on $\partial{D}$ since we have the condition $x^2+8y^2=24.$ I found that $(-4,1),(-4,-1),(4,1)$ are critical points.

Now I have to find the extreme values inside $D$. $\nabla f(x,y)=(2xy,x^2)=(0,0)$ gives me that every $(0,y)$ is a critical point. However, I'm not sure how to get extremes from here, since I cannot use the determinant test. Would be a possibility to use the monotony of $x^2$ depending the sign of $y$?

Comment: By derivating, you get local extremum candidates. By comparing the corresponding $(f(.)$ values (= 0) to your local extreme values, you determine that these points do not correspond to global extrema. The End.

Comment: Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892088

Answer (score 1):

$24\geq x^2+8y^2=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+8y^2\geq 3\sqrt[3]{2x^4y^2}=3\sqrt[3]{2}(x^2y)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ by AM-GM inequality. Maximal value for $x^2y$ is attained for $x=4y=4$ and it is $16$.

Answer (score 0):

Rescaling any point with $x^2+8y^2<24$ so that $x^2+8y^2=24$ increases $|x^2y|$, so extrema of $x^2y$, which can change its sign under $(x,\,y)\mapsto(x,\,-y)$, satisfy $x^2+8y^2=24$, so we should extremize $8y(3-y^2)$. The first two derivatives of this are $24(1-y^2),\,-48y$, so at $y=1$ ($y=-1$) with $x^2=16$ we have a maximum (minimum) with $f=16$ ($f=-16$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Question, I don't understand how you get $8y(3-y^2)$

Comment: @FabrizioGambelin If $x^2=24-8y^2=8(3-y^2)$ then $x^2y=8y(3-y^2)$.

Comment: I know the border critical points. I don't understand your analysis inside $D$.

Comment: @FabrizioGambelin A point satisfying $x^2+8y^2=24k^2$ with $k\in[0,\,1)$ won't extremize $x^2y$ because $(x,\,y)\mapsto(x/k,\,y/k)$ will multiply $x^2y$ by $k^{-3}>1$.

Comment: The Hessian is all zeros at (0,0) so it is an inflection point and can't be maximum or minimum

Comment: @am301 Sorry, that should have been $k\in(0,\,1)$. But your argument takes care of $k=0$. So only $k=1$ can give extrema.

Comment: @J.G. I am referring to the interior point where the OP found that the gradient is zero.  I wanted to show that it can't be a  minimum or a maximum and therefore they can only be on the boundary, where you have calculated them.

Comment: @am301 Well, that's easy enough: note that $x=y=0\implies f=0$, and positive and negative values of $f$ are obtainable in a neighbourhood of the origin, e.g. $x=\epsilon,\,y=\pm\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Let $z=x^2/y$, then $z\le -8y^3+24y$, $f(y)=-8y^3+24y, f'(y)=-24(y^2-1)=0 \implies y=\pm 1, f_{max}=16, f_{min}=-16$

Comment: @J.G. -  I Agree, this is a simpler way of showing the same thing